# Finding consecutive and identical integer into a vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have vectors with 0 and 1.

```
a = np.array([1,1,0,0])
b = np.array([1,0,0,1])
c = np.array([0 1 1 0])
d = np.array([0 1 0 1])
```

I would like to implement a function checking if the 1 are consecutive in the vector by disregarding the end of the vector, i.e. last element wih first element. Expected results will be:

```
check(a) --> True
check(b) --> True
check(c) --> True
check(d) --> False
```

The easy solution will be to scroll through each vector. However I feel that an easier and smarter is doable with some np.diff or np.nonzero combination. Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `shift` by one element; `and` the vectors.  Make a special check for the ends.

Comment: Try rotating the vector and computing the hamming distance vector. A `0` in the dist vector should result in a `True`

Comment: @Prune: you FGITW'd me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [np.roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html) + [np.logical_and](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) + [np.count_nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html)

```
import numpy as np


def check(arr):
    return np.count_nonzero(np.logical_and(np.roll(arr, 1), arr)) > 0


a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0])
b = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1])
c = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
d = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])

print(check(a))
print(check(b))
print(check(c))
print(check(d))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: Work perfectly and very smart. I will try to update it an array version (axis-like) to fully lever its potential.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this,

```
def check(k):
    return any( i in np.diff(np.where(k==1)) for i in [1, len(k)-1])
```

`np.where(k==1)`, this will return a list of indices where your vector is 1.

`np.diff(np.where(k==1))`, this will evalute the difference between consequative indices where your vector is 1.

Finally `any( i in np.diff(np.where(k==1)) for i in [1, len(k)-1])` this will check if there are consecutive 1's. Either if their difference is 1 or length of your vector - 1.